# Extend Valve For Hard To Reach Shutoff

Tags: plumbing, valve

In my cottage, I have valves that are used to drain the water lines.  These valves are in the well pit and are hard to reach.  I have to do some other repairs and while I'm doing those, I'm wondering if there is a way to extend the valve handle making it easier to open/close the valves without climbing over the other valves and filter, which I broke last time I drained the cottage.  ;)

Is this possible?...or is my best bet, just to move things around and make it easier to access the valves?

Comment: Did you want something like the things you see when you google "stop tap key" and select "images". Ditto "tap handle extender".

Comment: A pic would help

Comment: YES I am looking for a "stop tap key".  I didn't realize those existed.  Thank you.  Make it an answer and I'll accept.  I was lacking the proper 
plumbing vocabulary.